# React state not updating correctly. Increase and decrease function does not work on first click, but works after subsequent clicks

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

React state not updating correctly. Increase and decrease function does not work on first click, but works after subsequent clicks. Subtotal value is always wrong. if quantity is 10 subtotal should be 105. But subtotal shows as 94.50

```
import React from "react";
import { Card, Button, CardDeck } from 'react-bootstrap';
import { useState } from "react";

import image from "../images/image.PNG";
import "./productcard.css";

function ProductCard() {
    const price = Number(10.50);
    const [quantity, setQuantity] = useState(0);
    const [subtotal, setSubtotal] = useState(0);
    function calculatesubtotal() {
        const sub = quantity * price;
        setSubtotal(sub);
    }
    function increase() {
        setQuantity(quantity+ 1 );     
        calculatesubtotal();   
    }
    function decrease(e) {
        setQuantity(quantity- 1);
        calculatesubtotal();
        e.stopPropagation();
    }

    return (
        <Card className="card" onClick={increase}>
  <Card.Img className="image" variant="top" src={image} />
  <Card.Body className="body">
    <Card.Title className="title">White Bread 700g</Card.Title>
  </Card.Body>
  <label className="quantity-label">QTY</label>
  <div className="quantity-area">
  <Button className="increase-button" variant="primary" onClick={increase}>+</Button>
  <input className="quantity" type="number" value={quantity}/>
  <Button className="decrease-button" variant="primary" onClick={decrease}>-</Button>
  </div>
  <label className="price-label" >Price</label>
  <input className="price" type="number" value={price} />  
  <label className="subtotal-label" >Subtotal</label>
  <input className="subtotal" type="number" value={subtotal}/>
    
    
</Card>
    );
}

export default ProductCard;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
 function increase() {
        setQuantity(quantity+ 1 );     
        calculatesubtotal();   
    }
```

Because here when you update the `quantity`, the `quantity` *read* inside the `calculatesubtotal` still refers to the [old](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54069253/the-usestate-set-method-is-not-reflecting-a-change-immediately) value.
You can pass the new value to `calculatesubtotal` and use that inside.

```
function increase() {
        let newQt = quantity+ 1 ;
        setQuantity(newQt);     
        calculatesubtotal(newQt); // Modify calculatesubtotal accordingly
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

When you have a value that depends directly from another state value, it's a good practice to do not duplicate it at state, but just perform the calculation every time the state value changes:

```
    const price = Number(10.50);
    const [quantity, setQuantity] = useState(0);

    function increase() {
        setQuantity(quantity+ 1 );     
    }
    function decrease(e) {
        setQuantity(quantity- 1);
        e.stopPropagation();
    }

    const subtotal = useMemo(() => quantity * price,[quantity])
```

Way less code and a declarative approach.

Answer (score 0):

USe useEffect hook instead of  calculatesubtotal function as bellow

```
import React,{useEffect} from "react";

...

uesEffect(()=>{
setSubtotal(quantity * price);
},[quantity]]
```

```
import React,{useEffect} from "react";
import { Card, Button, CardDeck } from 'react-bootstrap';
import { useState } from "react";

import image from "../images/image.PNG";
import "./productcard.css";

function ProductCard() {
    const price = Number(10.50);
    const [quantity, setQuantity] = useState(0);
    const [subtotal, setSubtotal] = useState(0);

    uesEffect(()=>{
        setSubtotal(quantity * price);
    },[quantity]]

    function increase() {
        setQuantity(quantity+ 1 );     
    }
    function decrease(e) {
        setQuantity(quantity- 1);
        e.stopPropagation();
    }

    return (
        <Card className="card" onClick={increase}>
  <Card.Img className="image" variant="top" src={image} />
  <Card.Body className="body">
    <Card.Title className="title">White Bread 700g</Card.Title>
  </Card.Body>
  <label className="quantity-label">QTY</label>
  <div className="quantity-area">
  <Button className="increase-button" variant="primary" onClick={increase}>+</Button>
  <input className="quantity" type="number" value={quantity}/>
  <Button className="decrease-button" variant="primary" onClick={decrease}>-</Button>
  </div>
  <label className="price-label" >Price</label>
  <input className="price" type="number" value={price} />  
  <label className="subtotal-label" >Subtotal</label>
  <input className="subtotal" type="number" value={subtotal}/>
    
    
</Card>
    );
}

export default ProductCard;
```

explaination

whenever there is a change in quantity this useEffect will get called and update the subtotal base on latest quantity